# Calculate volume using Lidar in embedded system

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, volume, lidar

I am developing the system to calculate volume of the object using 2 Lidar.1 Lidar is placed left, other is placed right.
I am calculating the x-axis and y-axis position of these points. The object moves on the check weigher, so I can calculate the z*axis using the velocity of the check weigher.

I have, 45000 points data every object and all points have x-axis, y-axis and z-axis. Can you suggest me fast and accurate method to calculate the volume of the object in embedded system? I try to use Trapezoidal integration to calculate and volume, but it is not so accurate for the object. Because the object can be irregular shape.

There is a picture in below to understand easily what I mean. The picture shows the x-axis and y-axis of the points in one layer. And I have a 30 or 40 layers or every object.

[image]

Comment: _Side note:_ Which STM32 model? Are you sure you have enough CPU processing power to do these calculations? Do you need a GPU (e.g. nVidia Jetson) or an FPGA?

Comment: Surely this is a math question rather then an embedded system question?  Or at least getting it to run on an embedded system is secondary to getting the maths right.  Initially the mention of STM32 and embdded is a bit of a distraction.

Comment: If this is a commercial product (i.e. you can spend money rather then time), you might look at using MATLAB `boundary` function that can create a 3d boundary from a `cloud` of discrete points and return the volume of the enclosed space. ([example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html#buh3dcj)).  You can then perhaps use [MATLAB Embedded Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/index.html) to generate the C code for the target.  Googling "volume of a point cloud" yields some promising results (for algorithms, not specifically embedding on an STM32 target).

Comment: @CraigEstey I am using stm32f746-discovery board.